# Inequalities not displaying right output, JS

Tags: javascript, inequality

I am trying to make a simple final grade calculator and am having some issues with the output of the inequalities. It consists of 4 grades each given a double value. They are then multiplied by their respected weight and put into a series of inequalities to see which grade the participant would receive. Unfortunately, I am getting the incorrect letter value even though the double value is correct. I assume it's my inequalities, but I can't figure out whats wrong with them. Any help is greatly appreciated!

I didn't want to include all of the code because it's a lot, but they all correspond to their individual drop-down menus like this one.

```
<form name="GPA">
            <select name="demoSelect" onchange="showData2()">
        <option value="zilch">Select Quarter 1:</option>
        <option id="4.0" >A</option>
        <option id="3.5" >B+</option>
        <option id="3.0" >B</option>
        <option id="2.5" >C+</option>
        <option id="2.0" >C</option>
        <option id="1.5" >D</option>
        <option id="0.0" >F</option>
    </select>
        </form>
```

End of Form

```
function showData() {
        var theSelect = GPA.demoSelect;
        var firstGrade = document.getElementById('firstGrade');
        firstGrade.innerHTML = (theSelect[theSelect.selectedIndex].id);
        var grade = theSelect[theSelect.selectedIndex].id;
        var finalGrade = parseFloat(grade);

        var theSelect = GPA2.demoSelect2;
        var secondGrade = document.getElementById('secondGrade');
        secondGrade.innerHTML = (theSelect[theSelect.selectedIndex].id);
        var grade2 = theSelect[theSelect.selectedIndex].id;
        var finalGrade2 = parseFloat(grade2);

        var theSelect = GPA3.demoSelect3;
        var secondGrade = document.getElementById('thirdGrade');
        thirdGrade.innerHTML = (theSelect[theSelect.selectedIndex].id);
        var grade3 = theSelect[theSelect.selectedIndex].id;
        var finalGrade3 = parseFloat(grade3);

        var theSelect = GPA4.demoSelect4;
        var forthGrade = document.getElementById('forthGrade');
        forthGrade.innerHTML = (theSelect[theSelect.selectedIndex].id);
        var grade4 = theSelect[theSelect.selectedIndex].id;
        var finalGrade4 = parseFloat(grade4);


        var FinalCalc = ((finalGrade * 0.2) + (finalGrade2 * 0.3) + (finalGrade3 * 0.2) + (finalGrade4 * 0.3));

        if (FinalCalc >= 3.75) {
            document.getElementById("output2").innerHTML = "A";
        } else if (FinalCalc >= 3.25 && FinalCalc < 3.75) {
            document.getElementById("output2").innerHTML = "B+";

        } else if (FinalCalc >= 2.75 && FinalCalc < 3.25) {
            document.getElementById("output2").innerHTML = "B";

        } else if (FinalCalc >= 2.25 && FinalCalc < 2.75) {
            document.getElementById("output2").innerHTML = "C+";

        } else if (FinalCalc >= 1.75 && FinalCalc < 2.25) {
            document.getElementById("output2").innerHTML = "C";

        } else if (FinalCalc >= 1.25 && FinalCalc < 1.75) {
            document.getElementById("output2").innerHTML = "D";

        } else if (FinalCalc < 1.25) {
            document.getElementById("output2").innerHTML = "F";

        }
        document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = FinalCalc;

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The partial you have provided works fine:

```
function showData() {
        var theSelect = GPA.demoSelect;
        var firstGrade = document.getElementById('firstGrade');
        firstGrade.innerHTML = (theSelect[theSelect.selectedIndex].id);
        var grade = theSelect[theSelect.selectedIndex].id;
        var finalGrade = parseFloat(grade);

        var FinalCalc = finalGrade * 0.2
        //var FinalCalc = ((finalGrade * 0.2) + (finalGrade2 * 0.3) + (finalGrade3 * 0.2) + (finalGrade4 * 0.3));


        if (FinalCalc >= 3.75) {
            document.getElementById("output2").innerHTML = "A";
        } else if (FinalCalc >= 3.25 && FinalCalc < 3.75) {
            document.getElementById("output2").innerHTML = "B+";

        } else if (FinalCalc >= 2.75 && FinalCalc < 3.25) {
            document.getElementById("output2").innerHTML = "B";

        } else if (FinalCalc >= 2.25 && FinalCalc < 2.75) {
            document.getElementById("output2").innerHTML = "C+";

        } else if (FinalCalc >= 1.75 && FinalCalc < 2.25) {
            document.getElementById("output2").innerHTML = "C";

        } else if (FinalCalc >= 1.25 && FinalCalc < 1.75) {
            document.getElementById("output2").innerHTML = "D";

        } else if (FinalCalc < 1.25) {
            document.getElementById("output2").innerHTML = "F";

        }
        document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = FinalCalc;

    }
```

Check it out here: http://jsfiddle.net/wjvkg8q9/15/

Note that your function is called showData(), and the onchange event calls showData**2**()
Is it possible that you are editing wrong duplicated function in the rest of your code?

P.S: I have commented the other grade variables in the fiddle, but as you've said they correspond.

Comment: I'm such an idiot, the showData2 was not supposed to be there. Everything works great now. Thank you for the help!.